# MongoDB Java Driver: How to use $cond operator?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

I've written the following MongoDB update query:

```
db.getCollection("product").update(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        availability: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: ["$availability", true],
            },
            "Yes",
            "No",
          ],
        },
      },
    }
  ]
);
```

that updates all documents in `product` collection: set a new value for `availability` property based on its current value.

And I am trying to rewrite the query above for MongoDB Java driver:

```
db.getCollection("product")
     .updateMany(new BsonDocument(), Updates.set("available", "YES"));
```

but I am stuck with `$cond` operator, I don't know how to translate `$cond` operator from MongoDB query to Java driver.

Could you please suggest possible options?

Comment: Since you are using a _pipeline_ with the update operation the syntax is little different for the update method: [updateMany​(Bson filter, List<? extends Bson> update)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#updateMany(org.bson.conversions.Bson,java.util.List)). Here is an example: [updateMany based on other field in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212654/updatemany-based-on-other-field-in-mongodb/62227620#62227620)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different variation which requires `ClientSession` rather than `MongoClient`

```
UpdateResult updateResult = this.mongoColWrite.
                 updateMany(this.clientSession, new Document(), setUpdateList);
```

`empty doc` is the condition. You can add any condition there.

You have to provide the list for the update.

```
[
    {
      $set: {
        availability: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: ["$availability", true],
            },
            "Yes",
            "No",
          ],
        },
      },
    }
  ]

LinkedList<Object> condList = new LinkedList<Object>();
LinkedList<Object> eqArray = new LinkedList<Object>();
eqArray.add("$availability");
eqArray.add(true); 
condList.add(new Document("$eq"), eqArray);
condList.add("Yes");
condList.add("No");

Document availDoc = new Document("$cond", condList)
Document setDoc = new Document("$set", availDoc);

LinkedList<Document> setUpdateList = new LinkedList<Document>();
setUpdateList.add(setDoc);
```

This is how I usually does. Every array is a `list`. Every object is a `Document`.

[Example with older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606089/cond-operator-java-code)

Comment: got a feeling that there are some missing pieces

Comment: how did you get ClientSession obj?

Comment: OK, use this. `ClientSession session = mongoClient.startSession();`

Comment: on the local machine, I am getting the following error: Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected. Can we somehow avoid using ClientSession?

Comment: Yes, expected. Because its single standalone instance. You need to have replicas to make it work.